# Which is very unusual of me/for me

Tags: prepositions

Let's say you were always a champion marathon runner in the past. Then, you stop competing due to hectic schedule of school studies. Few years later, you joined again but you came in third only. Could you say:

> I only came in third, which is very unusual **of** me.

Or

> I only came in third, which is very unusual **for** me.

Which is correct prepostion?

Answer (score 3):

Because you are talking about yourself, you would say

> I only came in third, which is very unusual **for** me.

meaning

> This is very unusual ***for this to happen to*** me.

People talking about you might use either "***for***" or "***of***", for you to use "***of***" sounds like you are referring to yourself in the third person.

Comment: Hmm this is interesting, so you mean I can use both according to the context given above right?

Answer (score 1):

One of the usages of the preposition ***[of](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/of)*** is:

> used after an adjective when judging someone's behaviour:
>
> - *It was mean of you to mention her weight.
>     Thank you so much for my present. How thoughtful of you.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)